# What can I use to post new data in my flutter app everyday?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an app that is supposed to have a feature that would allow me to add new data daily into a screen. I thought about using Firebase console but I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to implement my feature. Could anyone suggest some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about sth like a NewsFeed? I did that several times using Firebase Firestore. I have a collection there called `news` and I have a model for that. Sth like:

```
class News {
   String title; 
   String description;
   String imageUrl;
}
```

And when starting the app I fetch all of them from Firestore and for each entry I am generating a NewsFeed Card on my Homescreen.

Maybe it's not exactly your use case, but hope it was helpful anyways.

Comment: What I want is to have something that the app owner can use to post trading signals in the app whenever they wish to

Comment: Why not using the model I described above with some more fields? Then you would need to build a tool for the traders who are giving the signals, which allows them to easily create new signals (items in the firestore)

Comment: I'll try it out! Thanks